# iOS AFNetworking (AFJSONRequestOperation) works in debug but not release mode

Tags: objective-c, ios5, afnetworking

I'm using AFJSONRequestOperation in an iPhone app (targeting iOS 5) - basically making a post to my website with various form data (including an image). This worked fine, and the live app-store version worked fine. I made some changes and Apple finally accepted my new binary - oddly the POST never hits my server now.

First thoughts: I broke it.
Rolled back to the original release and sure enough, it is still broken.

Now the weird part: In XCode, when I deploy the app to my iPhone (or simulator) it works, my server gets the POST and all is well. As soon as I deploy a release binary, it doesn't. Tried a few different IPAs via Testflight, and it is clear that the version Apple approved doesn't work.

Problem is, I obviously can't debug it because it works when debugging, and did previously.

Anyone had this experience, or know of a potential trip-up here?

I'm totally stumped.

Comment: Can you provide some example code so we're able to reproduce? Is there something special about that POST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the xcode 'Run app' scheme to use a release build, goto 'edit scheme', select 'run', then 'Build configuration' (under the 'Info' tab) to 'Release'.

It won't be perfect though, you'll get some oddities when debugging due to the optimiser having reordered code etc. You may have to add a large number of NSLog()s to trace through what path the code takes.

Comment: Thanks I'll give that a go. If all works out I'll accept, otherwise might come back for more ... :)

Comment: Nice. Ok, so the result was that I rewrote the code almost exactly the same but used `initWithRequest` then `setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:failure:` instead of initialising with `JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:success:failure`... Anyway. Being able to quickly go to release mode was the key to success, so thanks for the tip.